# How to make sure to unsubscribe users from Firebase FCM in a multi-account application?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an app for both iOS and Android that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to receive personalized updates from our application server. Our app supports multiple accounts to be signed in at the same time (think sharing a tablet with your family). Also, the same account can be used on multiple devices (like your phone and your tablet) at the same time.

When a user logs into his account, the app reports its FCM token and the account identifier to the server. Thus, the server knows that notifications for this user must be sent to that device.

Now, when an account is removed from a device (e.g. through the Android account settings menu), the app reports that event to the server as well to unsubscribe from notifications for this account. However, one could easily block TCP connections to our application server (e.g. when the user sits behind a corporate firewall), so the server would never know. The server would continue to notify the device, basically creating a privacy issue.

Is there a way I can ensure the server does not continue sending notifications to client devices for accounts that are no longer signed in?

Comment: Normally, I would suggest to use Topics Messaging as an *easier* way to send to a group of users. But in your scenario, it would seem that the messages you're sending is somehow confidential. For these specific cases, I would suggest for you to make use of a *normal* push (using `registration_ids` or `to`) instead of a topic. So that you can add in a custom payload parameter that can be used on your client-side to verify if  the current user is still eligible for the notification itself. That's just me though. Cheers!

Comment: There is also the option of handling the filter to which users it will be sent to via your App Server. Which would still make use of either `registration_ids` or `to`.